# pandas - selecting a lower level in a DataFrame to do a ffill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have such a DataFrame (is it a MultiIndexed DataFrame? I am not sure if I understand this correctly...):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index' : range(8),
'variable1' : ["A","A","B","B","A","B","B","A"],
'variable2' : ["a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"],
'variable3' : ["x","x","x","y","y","y","x","y"],
'result': [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]})

df2 = df.pivot_table(values='result',rows='index',cols=['variable1','variable2','variable3'])

variable1   A               B    
variable2   a       b       a   b
variable3   x   y   x   y   x   y
index                            
0           1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1         NaN NaN   0 NaN NaN NaN
2         NaN NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN
3         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1
4         NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
5         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   0
6         NaN NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN
7         NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN
```

Now what I want to do is `ffill()` the values, but only for `variable3 == 'y'`. The desired result is:

```
variable1   A               B    
variable2   a       b       a   b
variable3   x   y   x   y   x   y
index                            
0           1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1         NaN NaN   0 NaN NaN NaN
2         NaN NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN
3         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1
4         NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN   1
5         NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN   0
6         NaN   1 NaN NaN   0   0
7         NaN   1 NaN   1 NaN   0
```

I know I can do this by iterating over `variable1` and `variable2`, for each of them doing something like:

```
df2['A']['a']['y'].ffill()
```

But I guess there should be a method to avoid this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit tricky because of the need to assign the results.

First swap the levels, putting variable 3 at the top; ffill is then easily computed 
and assigned back.

```
In [44]: x = df2.swaplevel('variable1','variable3',axis=1)

In [45]: x['y'] = x['y'].ffill()

In [46]: x.swaplevel('variable3','variable1',axis=1)
Out[46]: 
variable1   A               B    
variable2   a       b       a   b
variable3   x   y   x   y   x   y
index                            
0           1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1         NaN NaN   0 NaN NaN NaN
2         NaN NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN
3         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1
4         NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN   1
5         NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN   0
6         NaN   1 NaN NaN   0   0
7         NaN   1 NaN   1 NaN   0
```

In 0.13 (coming soon), you can do this

Select the sub-section that we want, and provide `drop_level=False` to return it as a full section (e.g. don't the level that we are selection on), and ffill it.

```
In [77]: df_sub = df2.xs('y',level='variable3',axis=1,drop_level=False).ffill()

In [78]: df_sub
Out[78]: 
variable1   A       B
variable2   a   b   b
variable3   y   y   y
index                
0         NaN NaN NaN
1         NaN NaN NaN
2         NaN NaN NaN
3         NaN NaN   1
4           1 NaN   1
5           1 NaN   0
6           1 NaN   0
7           1   1   0

In [79]: df2.loc[:,df_sub.columns] = df_sub

In [80]: df2
Out[80]: 
variable1   A               B    
variable2   a       b       a   b
variable3   x   y   x   y   x   y
index                            
0           1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1         NaN NaN   0 NaN NaN NaN
2         NaN NaN NaN NaN   0 NaN
3         NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1
4         NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN   1
5         NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN   0
6         NaN   1 NaN NaN   0   0
7         NaN   1 NaN   1 NaN   0
```

Comment: Great. In production situation I am struggling with `AttributeError: _ref_locs`, but I guess this is not related...

Comment: there were a few bugs in 0.12 that cause that to come up (its related to duplicates in columns).

Answer (score 0):

there might be a better way of doing this since pandas 0.14.0:

`df2.loc[:, (slice(None), slice(None), 'y')] = df2.loc[:, (slice(None), slice(None), 'y')].ffill()`

or

`idx = pd.IndexSlice
df2.loc[:, (idx[:,:,'y'])] =  df2.loc[:, (idx[:,:,'y'])].ffill()`